# Confused in how to insert a slack variable in a constraint inequality

Tags: optimization, constraint

According to my understanding, we should put a slack variable to equate an inequality constraint by inserting the slack variable in the side that is less than the other side. For example, if we have $4x+2<2$ this will be $4x+2+\text{slack_variable}=2$.

But in the example section of the [Slack Variable Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slack_variable), it says the following:

> By introducing the slack variable $y\ge0$, the inequality $Ax\le b$ can be converted to the equation $y-Ax+b = 0$.

Which means that the slack variable is inserted on the bigger side! Please someone explain this confusion.

Comment: The Wikipedia example is wrong.  It should be $Ax+y=b$.

Comment: FYI, I just fixed the Wikipedia entry.

Comment: Many thanks for all of you .